# Plural issue while cleaning recently viewed posts

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, plurals

Tapping on Clear History button in the Recently Viewed page shows "1 Visits" if the last day contains only one item:

> [image: 1s]

- App Version: 1.6.6
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.3.2 (Build 14F89)

Comment: You should be very afraid of [Jeff Atwood's big *S*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/63791#63791).

Comment: @PeterMortensen [already warned several times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A339911+%5Bplurals%5D) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.6.6.1.